# USB Keyboards with fingerprint scanner

Tags: keyboard, fingerprint

I am looking for keyboards with a built-in fingerprint scanner.

I have only come across three models which can be purchased online, those being:

- Microsoft Optical Desktop with fingerprint
- Cherry Biometric Keyboards
- IBM Preferred Pro USB Keyboard

Microsofts Keyboard looks very bloated and clumsy, while Cherry and IBM both use huge buttons that I don't like. I have found these ones:

http://ksikeyboards.com/items/ksi-1700-gffb/

http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/finger-login.php

which look like what I would want, but I cannot find a seller for those.

Does anyone know of any more biometric keyboards or resellers for the ones I linked?

Note: I am looking to get *one* keyboard, not a volume order.